# Как так сделать в Android Studio? Bottom navigation + FAB?

Tags: android, navigation

Всем привет! Никак не могу допетрить, уже 3 сутки сижу, читаю документацию, читаю вики на material io от Google, но никак не могу реализовать задуманное! Необходимо нижнюю навигацию сделать как на 1 фото, но получается максимум как на 2 фото... Я так понимаю это Bottom navigation + FAB, но ни в какую не реализуется, не знаю каким образом уже что делать...

[Надо так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzEye.jpg)
[А получилось так...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvl7Q.jpg)

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

bottom_nav_menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="История" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    android:title="Отчеты" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="Напоминания" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_other"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="Больше" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий пример с моего проекта. Подгоните под себя.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/detail_background"
tools:context=".view.activity.DetailActivity">

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/unstar_anim"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:lottie_fileName="unstar.json"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/star_anim"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:lottie_fileName="star.json"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/progress_anim"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:lottie_fileName="detail_progress.json"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:src="@drawable/mclaren" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/similar_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:text="@string/similar_images"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDetailPrimary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/similar_progress"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/similar_progress"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/similar_recycler"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/similar_recycler"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/similar_recycler"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/similar_recycler"
    app:lottie_fileName="detail_progress.json" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/similar_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:itemCount="6"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_similar" />

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/swipe_anim"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:lottie_fileName="swipe.json"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_full"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab_set_wall"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fullscreen"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_set_wall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wallpaper"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_detail"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Есть подробный туториал как это делать: https://devcolibri.com/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-part-1/

Comment: Не совсем получается... Вот код и в итоге приложение попросту вылетает:
[тыкни по ссылке на pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/iAgnyEKp)

Comment: Вот фото что получилось по коду, и оно в принципе устраивает по дизайну, как надо, но не выводятся из menu 4 пункта и приложение вылетает. Вот фото [тыкни на фото imgur.com](https://i.imgur.com/yJSISQX.png)

Comment: какая ошибка при краше приложения?

Comment: Не поменял в файле кое что поэтому, но теперь не крашит, но и в меню ничего нет.. Хотя menu привязано.. Не так как то привязал? [скриншот, тык](https://i.imgur.com/3KlfpK6.png)

Comment: вот тут объясняют как меню подключать https://devcolibri.com/implementing-bottomappbar-menu-and-navigation-part-2/

Comment: Да, пытаюсь по данной теме сделать. В итоге я в onCreate добавил - setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.nav_view)) , и добавил ниже метод onCreateOptionsMenu, получилось так:
`override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu, menu)
        return true
    }`

По итогу приложение просто закрывается, ошибок никаких нигде вообще не вижу...

Comment: А вот, теперь ругается на setSupportActionBar, ошибка - [ошибка на pastebin](https://pastebin.com/A7bt29Tu), и код - [код MainActivity.kt на pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pfNZM7JQ)

Comment: И как я понял, в этой статье объясняется как добавлять в верхнюю панель, а мне нужно в нижнюю...

Comment: нет там именно как добавить в нижнюю. я делал по этой статье